# I can't turn off mirroring

Tags: edit-mode, mirror

I've switched to Blender 2.8 a day ago and things are very confusing for me.

Here's what I did: I created a model and applied mirror modifier and then applied it. Then when I started editing vertices in edit mode, the vertices were being edited symmetrically. 
How do I turn off this symmetric editing behavior?

Comment: please show youre blend.file

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have the *X Mirror* option enabled in the *Properties* panel > *Active Tool* > *Mesh Options*?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was it. I turned it off and it works! Thanks!